# Create ssh key, but provide a passphrase at the command line

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

What is the shell command to generate a SSH key, but provide the passphrase as part of the command instead of standard input for automating this?

For example (pseudo code):

```
ssh-keygen -f ./id_rsa -t rsa --passphrase=my-secret-here
```

Thanks.

Comment: Passwords on command lines are a bad idea.  They show up in `ps` output.

Comment: Yeah I know, but need to automate this, and provide a passphrase.

Comment: Did you look at the manpage?  The answer is on the first line of the synopsis, at least for the version of OpenSSH on my Debian system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man ssh-keygen`:

```
    -N new_passphrase
         Provides the new passphrase.
```